# Remove tags from selection

Tags: javascript, html, dom, range

I've got the following code:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="editor">
    <p>This is example text with <span class="spoiler">spoiler<strong>s</strong></span></p>
  <p>The <span class="spoiler">spoiler</span> exists in multiple paragraphs</p>
</div>
<button onclick="removeSpoiler();">remove spoiler</button>
```

The user can select text and after that click on the button to remove the `<span class="spoiler">` formatting. After clicking the button, the text must be still selected.

For example: The user selects "with spoilers. The sp". He clicks on 'remove spoiler'. The desired output is:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="editor">
    <p>This is example text with spoiler<strong>s</strong></p>
  <p>The sp<span class="spoiler">oiler</span> exists in multiple paragraphs</p>
</div>
<button onclick="removeSpoiler();">remove spoiler</button>
```

A jsFiddle of my attempt (I really don't know where to go from there): http://jsfiddle.net/632cr/

Comment: How will the user know the text he is selecting is within a span element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest and easiest way to do this is to use [rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) framework and its [CSSClassApplier](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/CSSClassApplierModule) module.

It's easy and your code could look like this:

```
rangy.init();

var cssClassApplierModule = rangy.modules.CssClassApplier;
var classApplier = rangy.createCssClassApplier('spoiler');

function removeSpoiler(){
    classApplier.undoToSelection(editor);

    // it's some preview div
    $('#preview').text( $(editor).html() );
}
```

See the result demo [here](http://jsbin.com/oHUZAViB/1/).

Comment: Rangy is supposed to work in JSFiddle and I have managed to use it in the past. What's the problem?

Comment: @TimDown My bad, it's seems I did something wrong, I tried again and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are after here, but:

```
function removeSpoiler()
{
    var e=document.getElementsByClassName("spoiler");

    for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++)
        e[n].style.display="none";
}
```

will hide the spoiler spans when the button is clicked.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what i'm looking for. I'm looking for a kind of Wysiwyg functionality to remove the styling of the <span class="spoiler"> for the selection of the user.